# Convert python codec to text

Tags: python, file, codec

The code:

```
ff = open(outfile, 'rw').read().replace('\n','')
for n in list(eval(ff)):
    c = []
    c.append(n)
    print c
```

Output in file:

```
((592, (1, '\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd1\x81\xd1\x8f.', 0), (2, '\xd0\xa3\xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc.', 0), 
...
```

But I want to see letters, not coding. I
used `.decode()` with different codec, but only changed coding, not get letters

Comment: what kind of file is this? what is the file extension (.txt / .doc / ...)?

Comment: does `print open(outfile).read()` what you want?

Comment: how does your code even work? `eval` returns `None` which isn't an acceptable argument to `list`

Comment: what do you mean by "codec"?

Comment: file extension has the meaning? Why? Now made .txt, before no extension.
`print` not help after `eval and list`. About eval and list it is my first experience on python, hardly understand full value this function, but this working. Codec - may be right coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to read a file in python and print it line by line. you can use this snippet:

```
import sys
outfile = 'file path'

with open(outfile, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: thank for `stdout`, is good knowledge. Probably issue in `eval`, it is converts coding. I don`t now, may be.

Comment: but this not solution my problem

Comment: @rss, what are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry for my complicated turnover, my experience small yet.  I want convert all my coding `\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3` to letters only, but `.decode(different)` not help me.